# Flutter image always reload when I use in stateful

Tags: flutter

Anyone used to face this problem, please give me the solution of this issue.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add your code and could you please explain more about the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I use Image (NetworkImage) widget in Stateful, and every time I scroll, Image already reload again.

Comment: Are you using NetworkImage in listview ?

Comment: Yes I do that @MidhunMP

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to give you proper solution without code and proper description of the problem. If you want to prevent download the same image again again from Network. You can use [Cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

```
CachedNetworkImage(placeholder: (context, url) => CircularLoader(),
                      imageUrl: ImageUrl,
                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => ErrorImage(),
                    )
```